# Prestashop product list order by random when change page

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i have Prestashop 1.6.1.4. When i'm on category-> Product list, my products are order by "reference" ASC. When i go to page 2 or/and back to page 1 my order by is random...

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You must be able to handle this in your administration in Preferences -> Products -> Pagination tab.

Regards

Comment: Defaut sort : Product ref -- 
Default order : Ascending --
--
Already checked.

Comment: You have override in store ? If yes, disabled override and test